# Converting physical Win2008 Machine into Hyper-V virtual machine on same box. Change SID?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, vhd, sid

We only have one hardware box. We converted our C drive into a VHD. We want to run install Hyper-V on our server to then load the new VHD as a virtual machine.

We will be updating the physical box to 2012, but want to make sure the VHD file properly works in Hyper-V before attempting to upgrade the physical box to 2012 which will run the Hyper-V services.

Previously I thought I found the correct sysprep instructions but that was awhile back.

I can't find the proper steps to proceed so the virtual machine would not conflict with the physical machine.

Also the current server is not acting as a domain controller and does not use Active Directory. No clients connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

This article from Mark Russinovich is the authoritative answer on this:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx

Sysprep is still supported and should still be used when making clones of machines in a networked environment. Duplicated local machine SIDs are not really a problem per se as they are not typically exposed outside of that machine, but there are some caveats that would lead you to still want to use Sysprep, because Sysprep resets some other "machine-specific state" that isn't desirable to have duplicated in a networked environment.

So just run Sysprep. It certainly won't hurt.

Oh and here are the [instructions for using Sysprep](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298491). It's been the same for a very long time.